# Flutter Web Video Plays based on scrolling values

Tags: flutter, dart, scroll, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I am working on a Flutter website which shows just a full screen video. Now, this video won't play automatically or with the play/pause button; rather, tt will seek videos based on the user's scroll.

What I tried was to take the video player controller and a scroll controller and, using the video controller's seek method, pass the `scrollController` value in its listener.

The issue is **where should I use this scroll controller**?

`ListView` and `SingleChildScrollView` need content to get scroll values but I have nothing but a full screen video. I am still exploring lots of options, like `verticalDrag` from `GestureDetector`, etc. Any guidance or solution will be really helpful.

Comment: Excellent question, and good thinking on using the video controller to seek. You are very close! Let me write a small demo for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Listener` widget for this, and listen for `PointerScrollEvent`:

```
  Listener(
    onPointerSignal: (event) {
      if (event is PointerScrollEvent) {
        print('user scrolled: ${event.scrollDelta}');
      }
    },
    child: FlutterLogo(size: 2000),
  )
```

Demo:

[image: demo gif]

Full source code:

```
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  double _value = 0.5;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Flutter Demo')),
      body: Center(
        child: Listener(
          onPointerSignal: (event) {
            if (event is PointerScrollEvent) {
              print('user scrolled: ${event.scrollDelta}');
              setState(() {
                _value += event.scrollDelta.dy / 1000;
                _value = _value.clamp(0.0, 1.0);
              });
            }
          },
          child: LinearProgressIndicator(
            minHeight: 400,
            value: _value,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This exactly what I needed. I did some math for the values and it worked. Thank You!